# Inclusion in the Vitali Theorem of Non-measurable Sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In the following theorem, why does the inclusion $E \subseteq \bigcup_{\lambda \epsilon  [-2b,2b]\bigcap \mathbb{Q}} (\lambda + C_E)$ hold?

[image]

I'm not really sure how to describe this precisely, but I sort of get it.

When showing A is a subset of B, one begins with considering an arbitrary element of A and then showing it is an element of B, right?

So, here, it is assumed that x belongs to E, but I don't quite see how x is shown to be an element of $\bigcup_{\lambda \epsilon  [-2b,2b]\bigcap \mathbb{Q}} (\lambda + C_E)$.

Here is my attempt:

The following are true:

x=q+c

$c \ \epsilon \ C_E$

$q \ \epsilon \ [-2b,2b]\bigcap \mathbb{Q}$

Thus, the elements of $\bigcup_{\lambda \epsilon  [-2b,2b]\bigcap \mathbb{Q}} (\lambda + C_E)$ are q+c=x...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to show the inclusion $\displaystyle E \subseteq \bigcup_{\lambda \in [-2b, 2b] \cap \mathbb{Q}} (\lambda + C_E)$.  Thus, given $x \in E$ we must show that there is a rational $q \in [-2b, 2b] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x \in q + C_E$, i.e., such that $x = q + c$ for some $c \in C_E$.

That's exactly what the above proof does.  The set $C_E$ contains a representative for each equivalence class, so $x$ must be related to some $c \in C_E$.  Then $x - c = q$ for some $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, so $x = q + c$.  Since $x,c \in [-b,b]$, then $q \in [-2b, 2b]$.  Then $x = q + c \in q + C_E \subseteq \bigcup_{\lambda \in [-2b, 2b] \cap \mathbb{Q}} (\lambda + C_E)$.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yup.

Sigh. If only the book just said $x = q + c \in q + C_E \subseteq \bigcup_{\lambda \in [-2b, 2b] \cap \mathbb{Q}} (\lambda + C_E)$ in the first place.

Thanks.